# Tunneling electrons through a Josephson juction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electric-current, superconductivity

A [Josephson junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect) is a device made of two superconducting materials separated by a thin isolating layer. Without a potential difference between the superconductors the Cooper pairs are in coherent states $\psi_i=|\psi_i|e^{i\theta_i}$, where $i=1,2$ denotes the different superconductor pieces. One can show that a current 
$$I=I_0\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1),$$
flows across the junction even in the absence of external fields (DC Josephson Effect).

Two questions:

1. What happens with the phase $\theta$ of a Cooper pair after crossing the junction?
2. How come there is no time dependence in the DC Josephson Effect even though Copper pairs are migrating from one superconductor to the other? Should not this imply after some interval the current ceasses?

Comment: For item 1, I'm not sure what you're asking. For item 2, why do you *expect* the current to stop?

Comment: Does the phase suddenly change from $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$ as the cooper pair goes from region 1 to region 2? Should not the current stop after all cooper pairs have migrated from 1 to 2?

Comment: I believe $\psi_i$ is the macroscopic wave function and not the wave function of a cooper pair. This should answer the first question.

Comment: The phase difference $\theta_{1}-\theta_{2}$ is a phase *difference* between the two condensate, the phase $\theta_{1,2}$ by themselves are not well defined. You would have a DC Josephson effect if you were able to distinguish the energy difference when adding or extracting one electron from one electrode. It is usually hard to distinguish this because of the huge amount of electrons in experimental devices. The Josephson relations were first establish for two macroscopic superconductors, the total number of electrons were astronomically huge, and so one can distinguish DC and AC effects.